# C program to compute length of array

Tags: c, function, debugging

I'm learning C, and tried writing a function that, given an array of integer, returns the length of the array. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int length_of_array(int array[])
{
    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (array[i] != '\0') {
        length += 1;
        i += 1;
    }
    return length;
}

int main()
{
    int test_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("%d\n", length_of_array(test_array));
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile this code and run it, I says that the length of the array passed in is 14. Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C are NUL-terminated. Arrays are not (unless you explicitly do it yourself). The size of array is just the size of array: if allocated as a constant, you can find out the size with `sizeof` operator. If all you have is a plain pointer, you need to remember the size - there is no way in C to get it once you forget it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int test_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *test_ptr = test_array;
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(test_array) / sizeof(*test_array)); // correct
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(test_ptr) / sizeof(*test_ptr));     // incorrect
    return 0;
}
```